# Render jsx element depending by a condition using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create in my react application a component that will render an element with a message inside and this component should be triggered when a condition occur. For this i created:

```js
export const message = {
  success: (msg, setIsVisible) => (
    <Alert message={msg} setVisible={setIsVisible} variation="success" />
  ),
  danger: (msg, setIsVisible) => (
    <Alert message={msg} setVisible={setIsVisible} variation="danger" />
  ),
};
```

And after that i want to call one component or another depending by the condition:

```js
if (err) {
  message.danger(alert.message, setAlert);
}
```

When the `err` occur i expect to show component from `message.danger()`, but id does not happen. 
How to make visible the component from `message.danger()` when the condition occur and why  the idea does not work now?

Comment: Is `<div>{( err && message.danger(alert.message, setAlert))}</div>` not what you're looking for?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev the ERR occur inside a fetch function, so it will not work

Comment: You can track the err by putting the result of the fetch into a piece of state.